# Linux Mint 14 Hangs on Install

Tags: linux-mint

When installing LM14 Cinnamon or Mate 64bit or 32bit via DVD or USB stick, on an HP nc6400 notebook, the install hangs during the listing (package loading?) at a line that states:

```
[1.854885] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
```

I have tried multiple times with the different versions listed above and the install always stops at the above line.

An older HP laptop (nc6230) will install LM14 with no problems.
Both laptops have have ATI graphics cards.

LM13 installs with no problems whatsoever on the nc6400.

Answer (score 1):

The DRM is Direct Rendering Manager, a piece of kernel <--> graphics connection. Look for suggestions on installing in text mode or basic graphics. Once installed and updated, you can see how to fix this.